# If am printing a dataframe using the gt package, how can I indent specified rows?

Tags: html, r, dplyr, html-table, gt

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  row_names = c("Name", "Age") 
  Person_1= c("Alice", "25"),
  Person_2 = c("Bob", "30"),
  Person_3 = c("Charlie", "28"),
  Person_4 = c("David", "22")
)

data %>%
  gt(groupname_col = "var", rowname_col = "category") %>%
  tab_header(
    title = "Names and Ages"
) %>%
  cols_label(
    row_names = ""
    )
```

If I wanted to indent the Age row in the table, how would I do that while still using the gt() package?

Comment: Any luck? Seems like it should be an available option